# invalidate() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android graphics and new to java at the moment. Need some help here!

I'm trying to insert a value into the textfield and then draw a rectangle on the screen after clicking a button. However, I'm getting the error as written below.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public myBitmap dest1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dest1 = (myBitmap)findViewById(R.id.myBitmap1);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
       final EditText d1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                {

                    dest1.invalidate();
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

myBitmap class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.drawing.R;

public class myBitmap extends View{
    public static Paint paint;
    static Canvas Mcanvas;
    static Context context;


    Bitmap bitmap;


    public myBitmap(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init(context);

    }

    public myBitmap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context){     
        paint = new Paint();                
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);          
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);            
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    }


    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50, paint);

        if(bitmap !=null)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Error log:

```
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261): Process: com.example.drawing, PID: 29261
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.drawing.myBitmap.postInvalidate()' on a null object reference
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at com.example.drawing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-17 17:22:16.916: E/AndroidRuntime(29261):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Activity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.drawing.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="154dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <com.example.drawing.myBitmap
        android:id="@+id/myBitmap1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding constructors, you need to pass all of the attributes to the super before continuing.

You have only passed the first one here:

```
public myBitmap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context);
```

Try adding another so that it passes the Context and AttributeSet.

```
public myBitmap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
```

I've not tested it, but it should get rid of your null object error.

Check out the documentation here for more detail: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

The inflate action occurs at the end of the super call, so when you're calling the other super method, it's never actually inflating your XML myBitmap element. 
That's why it's still null when you try to invalidate it.

**The second bit...**

The next issue is that you'll still see nothing, even though you're doing (nearly) everything right.

Take a closer look at drawRect(...) in your myBitmap class' onDraw method.

```
canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50, paint);
```

The [documentation for Canvas.drawRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) gives you a few options. The one you're using is this one, that takes five parameters:

```
drawRect(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)
```

So your call with all 50's is saying: *draw a rectangle with its top left corner at (50,50) and bottom right corner at (50,50)*. That means that although it's drawing something, it has a width and height of 0.

Easy mistake to make because it'd make sense for the second two values to be width and height not end coordinates, but that's not the case here.

So correcting that line to something like:

```
canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 500, 500, paint);
```

That'll draw a rectangle of dimens 450 x 450, starting at (50,50) and ending at (500,500).

Try that out and see if it works for you, hope it helps.

Comment: Yeap! It solved the Null object error! Thank you so much! However, nothing is being drawn onto my screen. Mind fixing my codes a little? I spent hours scratching my head for this =(

Comment: Hey, sorry I just saw this, I'd have replied sooner. I'll add to the answer now; I've just realised your other issue.